# Simulating bag of coins, to calculate mean number of false positive and false negative using ggplot

Tags: r

**Question**

Hello, I am simulating a bag of coins where 50% is fair and other 50% in biased with p=0.5 + q for some values of q. So i am using different methods such as

a) no correction

b) Holm correction

c) BH correction to calculate the mean of false positive (FP) and
   mean of true positive (TP)

**Problem**

I use a code which i will post below, the problem is when i run the plots my no correction shows data on the graph, but my other two methods Holm correction and BH correction, do not show any data points. Could you please tell me where i am going wrong and how to fix it?

I have one error message that says

`NAUnknown or uninitialised column: 'rej_holm'.argument is not numeric or logical: returning`

**Code used**

```
# simulating a mix of fair and biased coins function runs a 
# simulation of Ntosses of Nfair fair coins and Nbiased biased coins where 
# biased coins have success probability 0.5+ returns a dataframe containing the 
#true positive rate and false positive rate for each simulation

simulate_test_mixed_bag <- function(Nfair,Nbiased,q,Ntosses,alpha=0.05) {
    # simulate coin tosses
    faircoins <- rbinom(Nfair,Ntosses,0.5) #0.5 ensures 50% of coins being fair and 50% coins being biased
    biasedcoins <- rbinom(Nbiased,Ntosses,0.5+q)
    coins <- c(faircoins,biasedcoins)
    groundtruth <- c( rep(FALSE,Nfair), rep(TRUE,Nbiased) )
    cointests <- map_df(coins, function(x) tidy(binom.test(x,Ntosses,p=0.5)) ) %>%
        mutate(rej_uncorrected = p.value<alpha, 
        rej_holm = p.adjust(p.value,method='holm')<alpha,
        rej_BH = p.adjust(p.value,method='BH')<alpha)
    # return the mean of false positives and true positives
    df = cointests %>%
        mutate(groundtruth = if_else(groundtruth,'True Positive','False Positive')) %>%
        group_by(groundtruth) %>%
        summarise(uncorrected = mean(rej_uncorrected),
                  holm = mean(rej_holm),
                      BH = mean(rej_BH )) %>%
        mutate( q=q )
      return(df)
    }

    # run the simulation many times
    Nreps <-200
    Nfair <- 20
    Nbiased <- 20
    Ntosses <- 100
    qs <- c(0.025,0.05,0.075,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25) #Simulation done to run different values of q
    alpha = 0.05
    # we use map_df to run simulations for each q (inner map_df), and repeat this Nreps time (outer map_df)
    reps <- map_df(1:Nreps, ~ map_df(qs, ~ simulate_test_mixed_bag(Nfair, Nbiased, .x, Ntosses, alpha)))
    # we want the mean TPR and FPR over repetitions, separately for each value of q
    results <- reps %>% group_by(groundtruth,q) %>% 
    summarise( uncorrected=mean(uncorrected), holm = mean(cointests$rej_holm), BH = mean(cointests$rej_BH ) )
    ggplot(results, aes(q, uncorrected)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~groundtruth, scales = "free")
    ggplot(results, aes(q, holm)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~groundtruth, scales = "free")
    ggplot(results, aes(q, BH)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~groundtruth, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: can you narrow down the problem to one specific point. I think it's all NAs for one value, thats why you can get this plot. Can you check that and trim your code? It's really long and I think the issue is not with the plotting

Comment: For your code `...holm = mean(cointests$rej_holm), BH = mean(cointests$rej_BH)` you do not have a variable `cointests` available outside of your function in your example.